# Promise.all() for set of await functions

Tags: javascript

I have next code

```
const size = await getSize({someValues});
const count = await getCount({someValues});
const temp = await getTemp({someValues});
```

How I can do Promise.all() for this set of methods and get return results?

Comment: `const [size, count, temp] = await Promise.all([...])`?

Answer (score 4):

```js
const [size, count, temp] = await Promise.all([
  getSize({someValues}),
  getCount({someValues}),
  getTemp({someValues}),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const size =  getSize({someValues});
const count = getCount({someValues});
const temp =  getTemp({someValues});

Promise.all(size,count,temp)
```

Comment: in this case size will be like 123, count 7, temp 24 for example, after Promise.all(size,count,temp)?